# When reopen vscode, Ctrl + Shift + T wont work

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I close all tabs and then reopen vscode. I expect that I can use `Ctrl+Shift+T` to open the tabs I closed. But I can't. When use `Ctrl+P`, the file history is still there. So I am confused. Is there a setting for it?

Comment: vscode doesn't save old session data so ```Ctrl+Shift+T``` only works if you close files in the current session

Comment: Ok. I hoped it does just like modern Browser. eg.Chromium